# Jquery Selectors with multiple classes and same class name

Tags: jquery, html

In the following HTML every  has a span(class="flip") and div(class="panel").
I want to write a Jquery script that when a specific "Click Here" is clicked then the child of that specific element shows and when clicked again it hides.

```
<tbody>
<tr class="even">
    <td>
        <a href="something">
            1
        </a>
        <span class="flip"> Click Here
            <div class="panel" style="display: none;">Hello world!</div>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>        
<tr class="odd">
    <td>
        <a href="something">
            2
        </a>
        <span class="flip"> Click Here
            <div class="panel" style="display: none;">Hello world!</div>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
    <td>
        <a href="something">
            a
        </a>
        <span class="flip"> Click Here
            <div class="panel" style="display: none;">Hello world!</div>
        </span>
    </td>    
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
    <td>
        <a href="something">
            Glen Test
        </a>
        <span class="flip"> Click Here
            <div class="panel" style="display: none;">Hello world!</div>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Are you asking us to write the code for you?  Good questions show an attempt the solution to the problem.

Comment: `$('.flip').on('click', function() { $('.panel', this).toggle(); });`

Comment: Are you using HTML5? Otherwise the HTML code is invalid. In any other version a block element (`div`) can't be inside an inline element (`span`).

Comment: and sorry Erik Philips i tried some code but forgot to write it. What I was doing was I was not using "this" keyword. 
Instead I was doing the following
    $(".flip").find('.panel').toggle();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.flip').on('click', function() {
        $(this).find('.panel').toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="even">
        <td>
            <a href="something">
                1
            </a>
            <span class="flip"> Click Here
                <div class="panel" style="display: none;">Hello world!</div>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>        
    <tr class="odd">
        <td>
            <a href="something">
                2
            </a>
            <span class="flip"> Click Here
                <div class="panel" style="display: none;">Hello world!</div>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
        <td>
            <a href="something">
                a
            </a>
            <span class="flip"> Click Here
                <div class="panel" style="display: none;">Hello world!</div>
            </span>
        </td>    
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td>
            <a href="something">
                Glen Test
            </a>
            <span class="flip"> Click Here
                <div class="panel" style="display: none;">Hello world!</div>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```